# Is it possible to automatically highlight the top level of an enumeration?

Tags: enumerate, highlighting

The motivation for this question is :  I have an enumeration with depth = 2 (one level of nesting, not shown here) that is long, which is a page waster. One alternative is a) to inline it (`enumerate*`) but then it's difficult to tell the top from the nested enumeration. Another alternative, b), is to combine a) with a highlighter (say `\textbf`) for the top level. That's what I have done manually in the sample below. Is there a way to do it automatically?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{foo}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[foo,1]{label=\Roman*}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
\item
%  \lipsum[1][1]
  \textbf{\lipsum[1][1]}
\item
%  \lipsum[1][2]
  \textbf{\lipsum[1][2]}
  \end{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, you can use the `before` key to set some formatting that is scoped by the environment. Then, correct the `label` formatting as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{foo}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[foo,1]{label=\mdseries\Roman*,before=\bfseries}

\begin{document}

Stuff before \verb|foo|:
\begin{foo}
  \item \lipsum[1][1]
  \item \lipsum[1][2]
\end{foo}
Stuff after \verb|foo|.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any nested enumeration would have to start with `before=\normalfont`.

Comment: @Erwann: Correct. Even though your question discussion mentioned something about nested lists, it wasn't clear that it would be required for `foo`, as `foo` was defined as having only one level.